# SetAdapter in AbsListView.java - Buggy or am I missing something?

Tags: java, android, android-listview

I recently got a nullpointer-exception (calling showContextMenuForChild) in my ListView which extends from AbsListView. I couldn't find an error on my site so I looked into the sourcecode of AbsListView to find the reason behind this.

The method setAdapter seems a bit weird to me:

```
/**
 * {@inheritDoc}
 */
@Override
public void setAdapter(ListAdapter adapter) {
    if (adapter != null) {
        mAdapterHasStableIds = mAdapter.hasStableIds();
        if (mChoiceMode != CHOICE_MODE_NONE && mAdapterHasStableIds &&
                mCheckedIdStates == null) {
            mCheckedIdStates = new LongSparseArray<Integer>();
        }
    }

    if (mCheckStates != null) {
        mCheckStates.clear();
    }

    if (mCheckedIdStates != null) {
        mCheckedIdStates.clear();
    }
}
```

Why is this method not using the adapter at all? Funny to mention my "mistake" is, that the AbsListView tries to call mAdapter which is null. Did they forget to set the adapter in this class? This can't be true as this would have been seen by so many people and I could not find anything about this error on stackoverflow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`AbsListView` is not intended to be used directly but via a subclass such as `ListView` or `GridView`.

The subclass implementation of `setAdapter()` sets up `mAdapter` and only then calls `super.setAdapter()`.

For reference, here's a [link to `ListView.setAdapter()` source](http://androidxref.com/4.4.3_r1.1/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/android/widget/ListView.java#457). You can see how it works together with `AbsListView`.

So it's not buggy in this regard but arguably smells a little funny.

Comment: Thanks very much... you're right, the subclasses set the Adapter. But Basically if you extend from this class and you don't set this value you'd get a problem... not the cleanest code ;)